# Ajax PhoneGap always error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cordova

I must make an application, and I've decided to use [PhoneGap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhoneGap), but my Ajax always say "ERROR", and I don't know why, because the insert works very well...

```
$("#test").click(function() {
    var name = $("#name").val();
    var password = $("#password").val();
    alert(name+' '+password);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://191.165.1.16/PULZ/ajax_action.php",
        // contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        data : {
            actionname : 'insert',
            name:name,
            password:password
        },
        success: function(data) {
            alert("work");
        },
        error: function(data) {
            alert("There was an error loading the feed");
        }
    });
});
```

And my PHP code

```
if (isset($_POST["actionname"]) && !empty($_POST['actionname'])){
    $actionname = $_POST['actionname'];

    if($actionname == 'insert'){
        $connect = new PDOsql();
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $password = md5($_POST['password']);
        $sql="INSERT INTO user(name,password) VALUES(?,?)";
        $opt = array($name, $password);
        $connect->query($sql,$opt);

        $connect = null;

        die(
            json_encode(
                array(
                    'state'=>'success'
                )
            )
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Try removing "type: ", "url:", "dataType: ", etc, just leave the values

Comment: Just give back an json string from your php, to check if there might be a problem... if it then works fine, you know where to search...

Comment: Do you actually have a class `PDOsql`? And does your `query()` method of that class both prepare and execute the query? And check the console for the response given.

Comment: check the php url by directly on address bar and give the post values hardcoded and see what is the output. If you get any error or warning on response your ajax will fail as it is json accepting

Comment: `header('Content-Type: application/json');` ?

Comment: I don't understand davidvelilla, if I remove url, how he can knows where is the file ? 

I'll try reyaner 

Yes I hava a PDOsql class, she makes connection, and she's working very well

Comment: No, do not remove the url, remove "url: ". The keys. Not the values.

Comment: Anyway, it's just a happy guess to be honest. Check both sever/client side separately. Try calling the server script from curl command, or Postman, and see what it returns, what format it is, etc. Then when you are sure that works, make the client side call it properly

Comment: That's not work davidvelilla :/

Comment: Where does it say "ERROR"?

Comment: It can't work because `Content-Type` is not `application/json`, there's no error, ajax calls after request error instead of success

Comment: davidvelilla, It don't saying error, but he makes my alert :
error: function(data) {
                alert("There was an error loading the feed");
            }

kmlnvm, I write this :

contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 

and it's not working

Comment: contentType != content-type, good God why?

Comment: content-type: "application/json; charset=utf-8" ?

Comment: I gave you line for php code, that you should place before send output to client.

Comment: That's not working :/

Comment: I find a solution  header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); !! 
thank you every one for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Try this

JAVASCRIPT

```
$("#test").click(function() {
    var name = $("#name").val();
    var password = $("#password").val();
    alert(name + ' ' + password);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://191.165.1.16/PULZ/ajax_action.php",
        // contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            actionname: 'insert',
            name: name,
            password: password
        },
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
        success: function(data) {
            alert("work");
        },
        error: function(data) {
            alert("There was an error loading the feed");
        }
    });
});
```

PHP

```
if (isset($_POST["actionname"]) && isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['password'])){
    $actionname = $_POST['actionname'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    if($actionname == 'insert'){
        $connect = new PDOsql();
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $password = md5($_POST['password']);
        $sql="INSERT INTO user(name,password) VALUES($name,$password)";
        $opt = array($name, $password);
        $connect->query($sql,$opt);

        $connect = null;

        die(
            json_encode(
                array(
                    'state'=>'success'
                )
            )
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't use "empty()" with a non variable element, you will receive a internal server error "500", always.

> Note: Prior to PHP 5.5, empty() only supports variables; anything else
>   will result in a parse error. In other words, the following will not
>   work: empty(trim($name)). Instead, use trim($name) == false.

[PHP Manual - empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

Comment: `$_POST` is an array, so in OP code it's used correctly, no matter which PHP version OP is running.